# Imagick не читает svg

Tags: php, svg, imagick

Почему он не читает `svg`?

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="959" height="593"><path id="frames" fill="none" stroke="#A9A9A9" stroke-width="2" d="M215 493v55l36 45M0 425h147l68 68h85l54 54v46"/></svg>';
$imagick->readImageBlob($svg);
$imagick->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$imagick->adaptiveResizeImage(400, 400);
$imagick->getImagesBlob();
```

> no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно, [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30901533/5909792), нужно в строку с svg добавить `<?xml version="1.0"?>`:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="959" height="593"><path id="frames" fill="none" stroke="#A9A9A9" stroke-width="2" d="M215 493v55l36 45M0 425h147l68 68h85l54 54v46"/></svg>';
$imagick->readImageBlob($svg);
$imagick->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$imagick->adaptiveResizeImage(400, 400);
$imagick->getImagesBlob();
```